# What are the steps to install LoadRunner on Ubuntu?

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

What are the steps to Install LoadRunner on Ubuntu? Any link will also work.

Comment: what is ubantu? did you mean ubuntu, if yes this belongs on serverfault

Answer (score 3):

You cannot install loadrunner on any Linux machine. You can only run load generator on a unix box.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu is not noted as a supported distribution in the requirements, however Redhat is so noted.  Please refer to the requirements and installation guide for information on installing a load generator on Redhat linux.

You will face limitations on the types of virtual users you will be able to run with a linux-based load generator as many of the virtual user types are Windows API depedent.   You will also have an issue when you call for support, as the Windows-based generator is considered the "reference" generator for control and support.   So, if you have an issue and you contact support one of the very first things they will ask of you is to reproduce the problem on a windows-based load generator.   This will tell them if the problem is common to all generator types or to your specific generator type.